# How to get url value Passing From Laravel Route to php file?

Tags: php, url, laravel-5

I have an laravel application and also included an php file for a Payment Package,im Passing two url parameters from my laravel route to this Php File .How can i access the passed url parameters in this Php file.

```
Route::get('payumoneypayment/{courseid}/{userid}', function() {
    include_once(app_path() . '/payu/index.php');  
  });
```

The route passed from laravel is like this eg `http://127.0.0.1:8000/payumoneypayment/1152/44`
In my index.php file ,i tried using `$userid = $_REQUEST['userid'];` but im not getting the request value in php file

Comment: I'de suggest reading the documentation since you do not seem to understand some of the basic workings of Laravel. [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters), and take a look at [Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views) as well.

Comment: ok isure thanks for the info@Remy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do something like this:

```
Route::get('payumoneypayment/{courseid}/{userid}', function($courseid, $userid) {
    return view('payumoneypayment', [
        'courseid' => $courseid,
        'userid' => $userid,
    ]);  
});
```

After that, in your payumoneypayment view (file `payumoneypayment.blade.php`):

```
<?php
include_once(app_path() . '/payu/index.php');
```

And you will have the variables `$courseid` and `$userid` usable in your `index.php` file.

P.S. its not a good practice use `include_once` in a blade template file, just use its syntax (`@include` directive).